# What is the right way of calling sync and async methods (api / UI) in one method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

In the example below I call a Async method in a Sync method (UI).
In the Async method I call another Async method (api call for example) but I also call other sync methods (for example update combobox). Now I use Invoke((MethodInvoker... for every sync method call. Is this the correct way, can it better? No I also must think to use Invoke((MethodInvoker... when calling a sync method in an async one.

```
private void control_SelectionValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Task task = Task.Run(async () => await SomeMethodAsync());
}

private async Task SomeMethodAsync()
{
  Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => SomeMethodA))
  bool variable = await SomeOtherMethodAsync()
  if ( variable ) Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => SomeMethodB))
  Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => SomeMethodC))
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Task task = SomeMethodAsync()` in you non async method make more sense. And what is the logic with the MethodInvoker code?

Comment: Why would it make more sense? The methods called by Invoke are sync methods belonging to the UI thread. The SomeOtherMethodAsync is an api call (async).

Comment: That line makes no sense to me. You create a task just to await another task. Why not just return the first task (result of SomeMethodAsync) directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down what's happening here.

When your `control_SelectionValueChanged` handler fires, I assume we're running on the UI thread. You then:

- Kick off `SomeMethodAsync` on a thread pool thread via `Task.Run`. This does not block the UI thread.
- As soon as the thread pool thread begins executing `SomeMethodAsync` you are asking the runtime to marshal you *back* to the UI thread by calling `Control.Invoke`. While `SomeMethodA` is executing back on the UI thread, you are also blocking your thread pool thread at the same time.
- You then unblock the thread pool thread and ask it to execute some other `async` method. The entire operation will stay off the `UI` thread (unless there's something funky inside `SomeOtherMethodAsync`, i.e. another `Control.Invoke` call)
- After the `await` you return to *a* thread pool thread - this could be the same thread pool thread as prior to the `await`, or a different one - this is up to the `TaskScheduler`.
- If `variable` is `true`, you execute `SomeMethodB` on the UI thread (while blocking the thread pool thread, again).
- Finally, you execute `SomeMethodC` on the UI thread (while blocking the thread pool thread one last time).

As you can see, most of the time `SomeMethodAsync` is executing  (with the exception of the time spent awaiting `SomeOtherMethodAsync`, and brief periods between the `Control.Invoke` calls) you are still using the UI thread, but you are also *blocking* your thread pool thread. So you're now hogging two threads, mostly with only one of them doing useful work - the other one just sits there and waits.

In addition to being pretty horrendous to read, this is extremely inefficient.

Consider the following rewrite:

```
private async void control_SelectionValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await SomeMethodAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // We're an async void, so don't forget to handle exceptions.
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private async Task SomeMethodAsync()
{
    // We're on the UI thread, and we will stay on the UI
    // thread *at least* until we hit the `await` keyword.
    SomeMethodA();

    // We're still on the UI thread, but if `SomeOtherMethodAsync`
    // is a genuinely asynchronous method, we will go asynchronous
    // as soon as `SomeOtherMethodAsync` hits the its `await` on a
    // `Task` that does not transition to `Completed` state immediately.
    bool variable = await SomeOtherMethodAsync();

    // If you need stronger guarantees that `SomeOtherMethodAsync`
    // will stay off the UI thread, you can wrap it in Task.Run, so
    // that its synchronous portions (if any) run on a thread pool
    // thread (as opposed to the UI thread).
    // bool variable = await Task.Run(() => SomeOtherMethodAsync());

    // We're back on the UI thread for the remainder of this method.
    if ( variable ) SomeMethodB();

    // Still on the UI thread.
    SomeMethodC();
}
```

The above is similar (albeit not exactly equivalent) in terms of behaviour, but isn't it much easier to read?

Answer (score 2):

I would advise not mixing them. However the fact that you are in an event handler allows for an exception in the rule where you can have `async void`

```
private async void control_SelectionValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SomeMethodA(); //On UI
    bool variable = await SomeOtherMethodAsync(); // Non blocking
    //Back on UI
    if ( variable ) SomeMethodB();
    SomeMethodC();
}
```